# CakePHP PaginatorHelper: get current page

Tags: cakephp, pagination, helper

I need the page number but cannot seem to find any documentation towards it. How do I output in my CakePHP view the current page I am on (using PaginatorHelper)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->Paginator->current($model = null)
```

http://api.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper#method-PaginatorHelpercurrent

Answer (score 1):

After extracted $this->request via pr(), I got this solution

$currentPage = $this->request->paging['Model']['page']

and to put it to view
$this->set('currentPage', $currentPage)